# WPF DataGrid Last column not resizing properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using a DataGrid control to display some data and the last comun of the grid does not resize appropriately when the grid receives new data. When the grid loads is completely empty and data gets inserted after some user input. All other columns of the Grid behave as supposed to, any ideas of what I should do to make the last column resize?

My DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,4,4,4" ItemsSource="{Binding Order.OrderItems}" CanUserReorderColumns="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding OrderItem}" Height="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
              SelectionMode="Single" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SKU" Binding="{Binding SellerCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net Cost" Binding="{Binding UnitCost, StringFormat='£ #,##0.00'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Cost" Binding="{Binding TotalCost, StringFormat='£ #,##0.00'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gross" Binding="{Binding TotalCostWithVat, StringFormat='£ #,##0.00'}" Width="auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems that your last column is a calculated one. Did you implement property change notification for it after TotalCost is updated?

Comment: Hi icebat, you are right, it is a calculated column and I raise the appropriate notifications - otherwise it would not populate at all.

Comment: I have set the width for the description column to '*' in order to occupy all the available width of the grid and I believe this is what causes the issue

Comment: So the last column is emty until you interact with the grid, correct? 
if it's the only calculated property I still think something may be off with change notification. Can you show property definitions for TotalCostWithVat and the property it uses for calculation?

Comment: The whole grid is empty and all rows are populated after the user performs an action. It is not the only calculated field. I also moved the calculated fields at the front but I still get the same results. Additionally I noticed that every column on the left of the "Description" column gets resized appropriately and anything on the right is not, especially the last column.

Comment: Setting the column before the last one to star size seems to "fix" the sizing of the last column.